# how can i update UI to show "WebRTC data channel" at match section in use by httptoolkit-server?

Tags: webrtc, http-toolkit, mockttp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFaeU.png)I've installed all httptoolkit-server and also the httptoolkit-ui to capture data and mock it up, i've installed mockrt,mockttp,docker,... plugin's too but i cant see "WebRTC data channel" in the match section like the image below
(picture is from httptoolkit blog : https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/developer-tools-decentralized-web/
how can i capture and mock RTC connection's in httptoolkit as it shown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of HTTP Toolkit. The feature you're looking for does not exist yet.

That blog post is just a proposal and an announcement of funding, and the screenshot is only an example mockup of the future UI.

This will be available within the new few months (keep an eye on that blog and [the mailing list](https://httptoolkit.tech/keep-me-updated/) for updates) but it's not available today.

(I think you also emailed me earlier asking about this, and I replied there - feel free to respond by email if you want to discuss this further).

Comment: Thank you,
I am counting down from now :D

Comment: Just an update: this is now released! If you launch a Chromium-based browser via HTTP Toolkit, all traffic sent & received over WebRTC connections will be intercepted and will appear in the app for debugging.